# How can I run Excel Macro from Java?

Tags: java, excel, vba

I've .txt files generated by Java (with databases queries). I need to generate an excel with that (with graphics and other kind of information, is not just a pure csv).

How can I call my excel macro using java?

Answer (score 0):

I would say, have your Excel macro use the csv as a data source and let it do it's job directly.

Otherwise you might want to look into a reporting framework like jasper reports http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a JAVA-to-COM bridge, such as Jacob.  http://danadler.com/jacob/ there are other out there but I am familiar with Jacob. Then you would be able to start the application, load the file, run the macro, and then close the application. This should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create an excel directly using java apache poi, instead of creating txt and then converting txt excel using macro.